# Trying to manipulate the DOM to add attributes to a few tags on an ASP.net page

Tags: asp.net, html, dom

I wasnt sure why but the

```
 ]>
```

Keeps showing on my document, so i was thinking it was not be intepretted correctly.  My top of the page looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
[
  <!ATTLIST span parentNode CDATA #IMPLIED>
  <!ATTLIST span value CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

I wasnt sure why.  The complete name of the head of my file is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebFormDesignerFrameset.aspx.cs" Inherits="BICWeb.WebFormDesignerFrameset" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="InspectTech.Web.WebControls" Namespace="InspectTech.Web.WebControls"
TagPrefix="iwc" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
[
  <!ATTLIST span parentNode CDATA #IMPLIED>
  <!ATTLIST span value CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to declare an `<!ELEMENT span EMPTY>` before your attributes.

You could look at http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/attlist_declaration.shtml for more informations.